# C++ : Image sequence wrongly loaded

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have thousand of images in a folder,
created using

```
file << output << counter << ".jpg"; 
counter++;
```

smtg1
smtg2
  .
  .
  .
smtg100

Now, using this line, I get

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
pic = imread(fn[i], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

smtg1
smtg10
smtg100
  .
  .
smtg109
smtg11
smtg110

It seems like it takes in images based on the first integer,   hence the image sequence are wrong.
Can anybody point out my mistake if I was doing anything wrong?
So that I am able to get the correct sequence from 1-1000?

Comment: Might be easier to output the files with leading zeroes. smtg0001, smtg0002, etc... If it's too late for that, you'll have to break the filenames up and sort them by the embedded number as a number.

Comment: *it takes in images based on the first integer* Your assumption is wrong. It takes images in lexical order based on ASCII codes.

Comment: *able to get the correct sequence* You should read file names and sort them using your own comparator. Then read images in the order of sorted filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [`cv::videoCapture`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a949d90b766ba42a6a93fe23a67785951).

You can specify a template string of your file names such as `".\\some\\folder\\smtg%d.jpg"`, and `videoCapture` will read the frames in the correct numerical order for you.

(Untested) code, to demonstrate the basic usage:

```
cv::VideoCapture images(".\\some\\folder\\smtg%d.jpg");
cv::Mat image;

while(true)
{
    images >> image;
    if (image.empty()) break;

    // do your processing...
}
```

For details on how the format specifiers work in the template string, you'll have to read up on the [printf family of functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).